# Graphics driver for AMD Radeon RX Vega 8 (Ryzen 4000)

Tags: gpu-driver

my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 can't identify the GPU.
it's an integrated GPU in AMD Ryzen 7 5800H

the laptop detailed information is below
https://www.notebookcheck.net/Xiaomi-RedmiBook-Pro-15-R7-5800H.557686.0.html

`lshw` shows the following infomation

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fce0000000-fcefffffff memory:fcf0000000-fcf01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d0400000-d047ffff
```

Can anyone help me out with proper driver information?

Comment: The 18.04 release is older than the hardware. AMD Graphics, especially those of the Ryzen series need newer kernels.

Comment: Yes, you're right and thanks for the reply. I recently switch to Arch Linux, the graphics card can be identified now.